# Неясность с файлом manifest`а

Tags: android-sdk, android

Доброго времени суток, ХэшКод!  
В файле манифеста, указано следующее:

**android:minSdkVersion="7"

    android:targetSdkVersion="8"**

В моем понимании приложение с таким манифестом должно запускаться только на устройствах с Android 2.1 и Android 2.2
Однако, приложение с этим манифестом прекрасно запускается на Nexus 7 (Android 4.2)
Скажите, это баг или фича или я некорректно понимаю устройство файла Manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**android:minSdkVersion="7"** - минимально поддерживаемая версия

**android:targetSdkVersion="8"** - под какой версией идет сборка

**android:maxSdkVersion="8"** - максимально поддерживаемая версия

Answer (score 1):

target - цель, то есть под эту версию собирается приложение, но работать на старших версиях оно все равно будет (если конечно не противоречит  новым стандартам, например сетевые операции прекрасно отработают из основного потока в младших версиях, но вылетят ошибкой в старших )